# How to remove multiple tags for a docker image except one

Tags: python, docker

I used multiple Python base images during playing with some stuff. Currently, I am using only one Python 2.7. I want to remove the rest of them but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

Output of `docker images`:

```
python              2                   fa8e55b2235d        2 months ago        673MB
python              2.7                 fa8e55b2235d        2 months ago        673MB
python              2.7.13              fa8e55b2235d        2 months ago        673MB
```

How can I remove the tags 2.7.13 and 2 from this?

The usual `docker rmi imageID` can´t work with this as they have the same ID.

Comment: try `docker rmi python:2.7.13` and `docker rmi python:2`

Comment: @JoaoVitorino worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 docker rmi python:2.7.13
```

and

```
 docker rmi python:2
```

Syntax is **repository:tag**